# Azure Databricks: Different result when comparing dbutils.fs.ls(PATH) vs os.path.exists(PATH)

Tags: azure-databricks, os.path

I get different results when running `dbutils.fs.ls(PATH)` vs `os.path.exists(PATH)`. I have removed the path in my azure blob so it should return **False** but with `os.path.exists(PATH)` is returns **True**.  What am I missing here?

Comment: `dbutils.fs.ls(PATH)` Is this returning `False`?

Comment: yes correnct. I saw i made a typo

Comment: Can you share the sample `PATH` ?

Comment: basically I'm doing: `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/raw/MY_PATH")` and `os.path.exists(f"/dbfs/mnt/raw/MY_PATH")`

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this and it's working fine for me.

I have one file `Sample1.csv` in my Blob storage and its returning desired result when it exists in both methods.

[image]

I deleted `Sample1.csv` in my blob storage.

[image]

You can see it is giving error for `dbutils.fs.ls()` and False for `os.path.exists()`.

[image]

Do this with another file and recheck from your end.

Comment: could you just check if the path exists? that is `os.path.exists("/dbfs/mnt/mnt1")`

Comment: Yeah, it is giving `True` for me https://i.imgur.com/EFmFdLT.png

Comment: do you have a folder called `mnt1` in azure blob? It should be removed automatically once you remove the csv-file...

Comment: its a mount point(container name).

Comment: ok, I have mount point  plus some folder for partitioning. So if I remove a file in `mount_point/partion_folder/my_file.csv` and remove my_file.csv and do `os.path.exists("mount_point/partion_folder/")`  it will give `True`.  `dbutils.fs.ls("mount_point/partion_folder/")` will give path does not exists

Comment: yeah you are right, `os.path.exists("mount_point/partion_folder/")` this one is giving True for me as well. But if we give file path it is giving False.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue: `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/...")` lists the file from the Azure Blob Storage correctly. `os.path.exists('/dbfs/mnt/...')` returns *False*.

Comment: @JavAlex, No I think its better to raise support ticket on it.